# How can I assign the OnClick event of a ToolButton at runtime?

Tags: delphi, runtime

I have a TToolBar created in design time with no ToolButtons. My idea is to create ToolButtons in runtime and place them there when my forms are created, just to show the user what forms are opened without needing to open a "Windows" menu in the main menu.

I have an unit named NavigationUtils.pas that I use to store the procedures / functions about navigation (as the creation of the buttons when my forms are created).

The question is: How can I configure the OnClick event when the ToolButtons are created?

Comment: `NewToolButton.OnClick := ...`

Comment: Hi, @DavidHeffernan, well, I've tried this and got the error: **NavigationUtils.pas(24): Incompatible types: 'TNotifyEvent' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'**

Comment: Well, the problem is exactly as described. You are trying to assign something that is not a `TNotifyEvent`.

Comment: Allright, so, how can I create an TNotifyEvent and assign it to my OnClick event?

Comment: Now I understand the problem. Please can you edit the question to include the missing information. And also showing some code as well as the error message would help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the comments it is clear that you are not assigning a `TNotifyEvent` to the `OnClick` event. The declaration of `TNotifyEvent` is:

```
TNotifyEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject) of object;
```

So you need a procedure, with a single parameter of type `TObject`, and the procedure must be the method of an object. So, something like this:

```
procedure TMyForm.ToolButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
```

And then you can assign it like so:

```
NewToolButton.OnClick := ToolButtonClick;
```

Comment: Yes and the event must be public.

Comment: @RolandBengtsson No. It can be private.

Comment: Hi, @DavidHeffernan. Man, I've found the solution following what you saw and adding the "MyOnClickEvent" in the main form, who contains a toolbar made in design time. I just configured the **toolbarFormsCustomDrawButton** toolbar's event, so I used the event's Sender as Sender to the procedure OnClick of that button created in runtime that searches for a form with the Sender's (TToolButton) caption. Thanks very much for the help!